# Java Generics and Reflection | How to instantiate a generic class

Tags: java, generics, reflection, syntax

it's friday evening so I may be a little slow but I can't figure out to solve what i thought it was a simple question.

I have basically this situation.

1) a base class MyDAO

```
public abstract class MyDAO<K, E> implements DAO<K, E> 
{
   ....
}
```

2) a bunch of MyDAO concrete class implementation in a given package, say:

```
public class TaxonomyDAO extends MyDAO<Integer,Taxonomy>{

    ....
}
```

Every class extending MyDAO basically add specific DAO features relevanto to their E element. I'm writing a generic factory whose goal is to use reflection to provide an instance of WhateverClassDAO if this class exists, and to return a base MyDAO if not. Let's assume K is always Integer.

I've written something like this:

```
public Object getDAOForEntity(Class c)
    {
        createEmfa();

        try {
            Class eDao = Class.forName(getClass().getPackage().getName()+c.getSimpleName()+"DAO");
            Constructor<?> cons = eDao.getConstructor(EntityManagerFactory.class);            
            return cons.newInstance(emfa);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            return new MyDAO<Integer,?????>(emfa) {};

        }         
    }
```

This class, given a `Class c` (say `WhateverClass`) try to use reflections to create an instance of `WhateverClassDAO` using a parametrized constructor. The `***DAO` classes are assumed to be in the same package of the factory (I tried to keep it simple enough to be posted here).

In the catch, since the reflection failed I assume there's no WhateverClassDAO so I'd like to return a `MyDAO<Integer,WhateverClass>` but I'm not able to pass the right `E` argument there. I tried passing `Class<E>` as an argument with no luck. I'm basically wondering what to substitute to ?????.

It's out of scope, but all this code is inside a Singleton EJB.

Any help, even in form of a link to proper documentation will be much appreciated.

Comment: Only Chuck Norris can instantiate an abstract class in java.

Comment: I hope I didnt offend. Just kidding ;) I would have just returned an optional absent if no such DAO exists.

Comment: I guess you could create the sub class on runtime and register it to spring's dependancy injection mechanism but that would be a challenge

Comment: No offence, i laughed at myself as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `Class` is also generic and you can infer the correct generic parameter from it:

```
public <E> Object getDAOForEntity(Class<E> c) {
    try {
        // ...
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        return new MyDAO<Integer,E>(emfa) {};
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that before, forgetting the type declaration < E > at the beginning of method declaration...7.20 PM here...time to have a break. Thank you for your quick answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You should make a generic method and also better make it return you dao base class instead of Object:

```
  public <E> MyDAO<Integer, E> getDAOForEntity(Class<E> c) {
    ...
    try {
      Class<MyDAO<Integer, E>> eDao = (Class<MyDAO<Integer, E>>)(Class<?>)Class.forName(getClass().getPackage().getName()+c.getSimpleName()+"DAO");
      Constructor<MyDAO<Integer, E>> cons = eDao.getConstructor(EntityManagerFactory.class);            
      return cons.newInstance(emfa);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
      return new MyDAO<Integer,E>(emfa) {};
    }         
  }
```

Comment: I'm returning that. I quickly edited the code before posting. Also the class names are not those

Comment: good. also to get rid of the warning on cast you can add   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")